# MySQL - join users latest level, not any level?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of `users`:

```
id | name
1  | Mike
```

I have a table of `rights`, which gives my users some rights, such as:

```
id | user | elevation | starts     | ends
1    1      2           1382950736   1383555536
```

Here I have elevated Mike to level 2 beginning at 1382950736 and ending at 1383555536. At this time range, the user is level 2. At other times, the user is level 1.

I have a query to find out what level a user is:

```
SELECT IF(`z`.`elevation` IS NULL, 1, `z`.`elevation`) as `elevation`, `users`.`id`
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT `user`, `elevation`
   FROM `rights`
   WHERE (`starts` <= $time) AND (`ends` > $time)
   GROUP BY `user`
) as `z` ON `z`.`user` = `users`.`id`
```

This is all great and works perfectly. However, I have a problem in cases where elevations overlap for a certain user.

For example: let's imagine, just for the sake of a simple example, that the **time now is 10**.

We create this entry:

```
id | user | elevation | starts     | ends
1    1      2           1            15
2    1      3           5            20
```

In this case, both entries meet the `` (`starts` <= $time) AND (`ends` > $time) `` condition (the current time is 10). What my SELECT query does in these cases is that it returns **level 2** for my users, although the latest entry for him is **level 3**.

How can I fix my query to return the **latest level, not any level, in case more levels overlap**?

Comment: Just to be clear, is `latest`equal to highest `starts` or to highest `id`

Comment: @Strawberry: ``latest`` equal to highest ``starts`` that is less than current time.

Comment: SELECT x.* FROM my_table JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(starts) max_starts FROM my_table GROUP BY user) y ON y.user=x.user AND y.max_starts = x.starts;

Comment: I tried MAX(`starts`). it doesn't work.

Comment: It works. You haven't studied my answer properly.

Comment: Maybe you should submit it as an answer and ideally use table names other than my_table so that we can understand what you're doing there.

Comment: I would use MAX in the subquery - just: `SELECT user, max(elevation) elevation`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(z.elevation,1) elevation
     , u.id
  FROM users u
  LEFT 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user
            , elevation
         FROM rights x
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT user,MAX(starts) max_starts FROM rights GROUP BY user ) y
           ON y.user = x.user
          AND y.max_starts = x.starts
        WHERE '$time' BETWEEN starts AND ends
     ) z
    ON z.user =  u.id
```

get it?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work properly. If the MAX(`starts`) entry for a certain user is after current time (not in effect yes), the query returns no privileges for the user, although in fact, he should have (older) privileges.

Comment: You probably have to include the time constraint within the JOIN condition - this would be easier with a sqlfiddle or at least proper DDLs.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really understand the logic behind the use case but why not use

```
order by elevation desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Because this doesn't work and because you don't always promote a user. you can also demote them.

Comment: then order by id desc

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select if(rs.user is null, 1, r.elevation) as elevation, u.id
from users u
left outer join rights r on u.id = r.user
left outer join (
   select user, max(starts) as starts
   from rights
   where (starts <= $time) AND (ends > $time)
   group by user
) rs on r.user = rs.user and r.starts = rs.starts
where r.user is null or (r.user is not null and rs.user is not null);
```